# Using Windows Azure to use as a TCP Server

Tags: azure

I'm looking into Windows Azure now and wondering if one can implement a TCP/IP server using Worker Roles - i.e, when a request comes in on a socket - a worker role (and not a web role) will accept it, treat it well and then return an answer on that same socket request.

Another question is - should I do it, or maybe just implement my own non-blocking server using .NET and put it in one worker role or a VM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a full worked example of a telnet server on Maaten Balliauw's blog - see http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/17/Creating-an-external-facing-Azure-Worker-Role-endpoint.aspx

On your second question, most answers seem to recommend using worker roles for code instead of using VMs - worker roles in general are "architecturally preferred" for Azure, and VMs are there mainly for when you need to support existing (legacy) code.

Comment: The URL has changed. https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/17/creating-an-external-facing-azure-worker-role-endpoint.html

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Stuart's answer: A Worker Role will give you nearly everything a VM role is going to offer you, without you having to worry about maintaining the OS. VM roles are needed for a few specific scenarios. I enumerated them in [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170703/working-with-file-compression-encryption-in-azure/6171420#6171420), but just for completeness, here are those scenarios which require a VM role:

- Startup / setup takes a really long time. This is a bit subjective, but a good rule-of-thumb is around 5 minutes. Remember that, every time your role instances boot up, they need to re-run any tasks in your startup, including software installs, so role instance availability is delayed until all startup tasks are run.
- Startup / setup tasks are unreliable and don't always work the first time you run them. Software setups need to run in unattended mode, and must reliably succeed.
- Human interaction is required. If the software install can't be completely automated, there's no way to script it.

When it comes to hosting a TCP service, you can choose to host something either publically available or only internal to your other role instances. For public hosts, you have up to 25 endpoints to work with across your deployment, and for internal hosts, you have up to 5 endpoints per role. See my blog post [here](http://www.davidmakogon.com/2011/05/windows-azure-tip-go-beyond-5-endpoints.html) for more details around this.